# javascript smooth scroll on click

Tags: javascript, scrolltop

I'm using this link:

```
<a class="" onclick="location.href='#top'" href="superContent">superContent</a>
```

It does two things at once:

1. Jumps user to top of the page
2. Performs this other (unrelated) ajax load function

Everything works great, except I'm trying to figure out how to get it to scroll to the top more smoothly. I've tried adding .scroll to attach it to my jquery scrollTo plugin, but nothing happens, which probably has something to do with the fact that I'm using javascript onclick, while the href attribute does something else entirely.

Is there a way to attach animated smooth-scrolling to onclick="location.href='#top'" ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this, it animates the `scrollTop()` function.

Set link's id:

```
<a id="link">link</a>
```

jquery to scroll:

```
$('#link').click(function(e){
  var $target = $('html,body');
  $target.animate({scrollTop: $target.height()}, 500);
});
```

Comment: 'return false' is definitely wrong here! Use 'function(e)..' and 'e.preventDefault()' instead.

Comment: It is beautiful and super clean code. The most important is, it works well!

Comment: As this question was asked without a jQuery tag, I'm expecting a plain JS solution.

Answer (score 5):

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
   scrollTo( document.querySelector('aside'), Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1  , 600 );   
});
    
function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
    var start = element.scrollTop,
        change = to - start,
        currentTime = 0,
        increment = 20;
        
    var animateScroll = function(){        
        currentTime += increment;
        var val = Math.easeInOutQuad(currentTime, start, change, duration);
        element.scrollTop = val;
        if(currentTime < duration) {
            setTimeout(animateScroll, increment);
        }
    };
    animateScroll();
}

//t = current time
//b = start value
//c = change in value
//d = duration
Math.easeInOutQuad = function (t, b, c, d) {
  t /= d/2;
  if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
  t--;
  return -c/2 * (t*(t-2) - 1) + b;
};
```

```css
button{ float:left; }
aside{ height:200px; width:50%; border:2px dashed red; overflow:auto; }
aside::before{
  content:''; 
  display:block; 
  height:1000px;  
  background: linear-gradient(#3f87a6, #ebf8e1, #f69d3c);
}
```

```html
<button>click to random scroll</button>
<aside></aside>
```