# anchor link - animating page back to page top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Wordpress Site; I am using simple code and anchor to send the user to the top of the page.

```
<body id="pg-top" <?php body_class(); ?> >

...

<a href="#pg-top">miss something?</a>
```

This sends the user directly to the top instantly. I want the user to be automatically "scrolled up", sent up the page at a certain speed.

Not sure if I explained this correctly, but I've seen this done on many websites. Gradual scroll back to the top of page on click

Comment: possible duplicate of [smooth scroll with javascript onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016379/smooth-scroll-with-javascript-onclick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jquery `animate` function  on hyperlink click event.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="scrolltop();">miss something?</a>
```

jquery

```
<script>
  function scrolltop(){
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0}, '500');
   }
</script>
```

you can change animation speed by changing duration parameter. here in my code it is `500`.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why `javascript:void(0)` instead of the classic `#`?

Comment: @D4V1D if we use   `#` it will alos add `#` in url. `javascript:void(0)`  will not add any extra params in url

Comment: @user3550879 you can add this function anywhere in page betweeen <script></script> tag. i dont have much idea about wordpress. but this is simple javascript function . you can add aneware in page. or in header or footer.

Comment: added it between my <head> tags, but no dice?

Comment: I am bringing query in dynamically and is being brought in before  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2"></script> is how it's brought in before the script

Comment: you can add this <script>
  function scrolltop(){
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0}, '500');
   }
</script>  function under this link. and make sure you call this function on hyperlink as i added in my answer

Comment: add function below this link <script type="text/javascript" src="localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/…;>

Comment: thats it! I don't know what I did wrong, but that code line worked

Answer (score 2):

This is one way that delegates a click event handler to all elements having `.scroll-top`. You can use it with links, but also all other elements. Due to the event delegation, this will also work with elements that are later added dynamically by other scripts.

```
$('body').on('click', '.scroll-top', function (e) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 300); // Speed: 0.3 seconds
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Now you can attach it to any element like in these examples:

```
<a class="scroll-top" href="#">top</a>
<span class="scroll-top">top</span>
<h1 class="scroll-top">top</h1>
```

**Example: https://jsfiddle.net/j1uct2z8/**

Comment: can that be written as a function that I can put in my page, with php or <script> since I am using wordpress, and beginner with code

Comment: Yes. Just put it between a `<script>` and `</script>`. It's Javascript/jQuery, having nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: well it brings people back to the top, but the animation doesn't seem to work, I put it in my <head> tags

Comment: Make sure jQuery is loaded before that code. Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/j1uct2z8/

Comment: is it based on a specific jQuery, I am bringing it in through wordless dynamically. It checks and brings in the most up to date jQuery.js

Comment: That's not a good idea, but this works in all current jQuery versions. In the jsfiddle, you can select a different jQuery version on the left to try out.