# Smooth same screen scrolling

Tags: html, css

I want to make it so I can click the link on my page and have it smoothly transition to the target, if anyone can help I would be very grateful.

Here is my button link,

```
<div class="btn"><a href="#work">Read More</a></div>
```

And below is the target,

```
<div class="sec2">
 <a name="work"><h1>My Work</h1></a>
 <center><img class="work1" src="img/work1.png" alt="Colour Booklet"></img></center>
    <p>How are trends in colour usage formulated in contemporary culture?</p>
```

I want it so I can click the button and have it scroll down smoothly.

Thanks.

Comment: You **need** to use JavaScript for this. jQuery version: [jQuery Smooth Scrolling](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) • [VanillaJS Smooth Scroll](http://cferdinandi.github.io/smooth-scroll/)

Comment: Oh really well this can be done with custom jquery code no need to use liberary for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016379/smooth-scroll-with-javascript-onclick